# just one Edit instead of two ( AlertDialog )

Tags: java, android, alert, edit, android-alertdialog

new day - new problem :

i want to have a button, which starts an `AlertDialog`, in which the user can change the range for a random number

my problem is : it only shows one edit, and i don't know why

(btw : the app doesn't crash : i get a random number, i just don't know where it comes from )

below is my code :

```
String s;

public void btn_own(View view) {
    int a, b, c;        // a : untere Grenze , b : obere Grenze


    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        alert.setTitle("Enter range");

        final EditText inputa = new EditText(this);
        final EditText inputb = new EditText(this);
        alert.setView(inputa);
        alert.setView(inputb);

            alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                    int aa = 0;
                    int bb = 0;
                    int cc = 0;
                    int e = 0;
                    try {
                        aa = Integer.parseInt(inputa.getText().toString());
                    }   catch (NumberFormatException f) {
                        System.out.println("not a number: " + inputa.getText().toString());
                        f.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try {
                        bb = Integer.parseInt(inputb.getText().toString());
                    }   catch (NumberFormatException g) {
                        System.out.println("not a number: " + inputb.getText().toString());
                        g.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    cc = bb - aa;
                    Random rand = new Random();
                    int d = rand.nextInt(cc);
                    e = d + bb;
                    Integer out = new Integer(e);
                    s = out.toString();

                    new AlertDialog.Builder(Decider.this)
                            .setMessage(s)
                            .show();

                }
            });
        alert.show();



}
```

hope you can help me .. i am new in development and that's my first real project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the second view it s overriding the first in AlertDialog you put only one view! so use a linearlayout trick as here below:

String s;

```
public void btn_own(View view) {
    int a, b, c;        // a : untere Grenze , b : obere Grenze


AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle("Enter range");
     LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
     linearLayout.setOrientation(1);
     linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);


    final EditText inputa = new EditText(this);
    final EditText inputb = new EditText(this);
     linearLayout.addView(inputa );
     linearLayout.addView(inputb );

    alert.setView(linearLayout );


        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                int aa = 0;
                int bb = 0;
                int cc = 0;
                int e = 0;
                try {
                    aa = Integer.parseInt(inputa.getText().toString());
                }   catch (NumberFormatException f) {
                    System.out.println("not a number: " + inputa.getText().toString());
                    f.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    bb = Integer.parseInt(inputb.getText().toString());
                }   catch (NumberFormatException g) {
                    System.out.println("not a number: " + inputb.getText().toString());
                    g.printStackTrace();
                }
                cc = bb - aa;
                Random rand = new Random();
                int d = rand.nextInt(cc);
                e = d + bb;
                Integer out = new Integer(e);
                s = out.toString();

                new AlertDialog.Builder(Decider.this)
                        .setMessage(s)
                        .show();

            }
        });
    alert.show();
```

}

Comment: thanks for the fast answer !

may a stupid question, but why cant he resolve symbol 'context' ?

  ------      LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);

Comment: ha ok you can get the context with getApplicationContext or with your ActivityName + ".this". so just replace context with that or just replace context with this

Comment: omg thank you soo much, 
i have two edits now 
the result is still wrong, but you helped me very much

Comment: your welcome. If my answer was the most helpfull for you please select it :)

Comment: i will :)

if its ok : one last question, why is the result still wrong ? :D 
i dont get it ....

Comment: you want to generate a random between the two input right?

Comment: Because i do not understand what you want to get as result

Comment: yeah exactly 
the user define the range
e.g. between 10 and 100 
and the app generates a random number between the borders 
e.g. 60 or 55 or what else 

i dont find my mistake ......

Comment: i see use this formula: Max+ (int)(Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1))
where Max = aa and min = bb

Comment: stil the same problem ... 

what is 'Math.random() doing ? and why do we multiplicate it with the Max - Min ?

Comment: should behave the same as the Random class. anyway rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min; try this last i dont know what else to do if its not working .if not post the code on how you implemented it.

Comment: if found this : 

http://blog.root-of-all-evil.com/2010/03/math-random-zufallszahlen-in-java/

(its on german, but understandable) 

 --------- so i used this : e = (int)(Math.random() * (Max - Min) + Min); ------
now its working . thank you for your help !!

Answer (score 1):

by "one edit", I assume you mean "one edittext". the reason why you are getting only one edittext is that you are using setView() method twice with two different edittext components.
setView() method is actually used to set the view of the dialog, so the solution to your problem is that you can use a layout file with two edittext's wrapped inside a linearlayout. here is how you can do this -

define a layout file in your layout folder like below and give a name to this layout file of your choice

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/set_default_header"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@drawable/lem_background_small"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:padding="10dp" >
     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/randomno1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text=""
        android:hint="Enter Budget"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/randomno2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text=""
        android:hint="Enter Budget"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
      </LinearLayout>
```

the in the setView() method write setView(R.layout.yourlayoutfilename) instead of

```
    alert.setView(inputa);
    alert.setView(inputb);
```

and then inside setPositiveButton() method of your dialog you can access these edittexts by their id and do what you want to.

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: thank you for your answer
i took the other solution, but now i understand my mistake thank you for that ! :)